# Adding multiple buttons to form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm calling on multiple buttons to show up but it seems that only one button shows up. Please tell me why. I've tried adding `a` in the body with a class but that seems to screw up the button that's already hidden.

This form basically shows a button when the url contains `iphone`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SDq4P/35/show/#iPhone
Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SDq4P/35/

I need all three buttons to show at one time. All three buttons contain `iphone` but only one shows up.

```
<div id="linkdiv" href="phone-condition" onclick="location.href = $(this).attr('href')+'?/1234/#iPhone';return false" />
<div id="linkdiv" href="phone-condition" onclick="location.href = $(this).attr('href')+'?/1234/#iPhone';return false" /> 
<div id="linkdiv" href="phone-condition" onclick="location.href = $(this).attr('href')+'?/1234/#iPhone';return false" />
```

Comment: Your divs are empty and they all have the same id. What exactly are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of class instead of IDs. HTML `ID` is supposed to be unique and your sample HTML has three `DIV` elements with the same `ID`. If you are using jQuery like `$('#linkDiv')` and do something, only the first element is selected.

Comment: I even tried a unique `id` for each button but they still don't show up. Only one button at a time does.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<div ...></div>` instead. I don't think you can end divs using the XHTML />. If you check in Chrome Dev Tools the buttons are nested into each other.

Comment: I think if you set the <!DOCTYPE accordingly you might be able to get away with using XHTML /> on div

Comment: UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/SDq4P/36/ | Is there any way I can get all three buttons to appear at once?

Comment: you need something inside the div for it to display, or give the div's a set height and width. some people just put &nbsp; inside empty divs.

Comment: The div's already are buttons. Check the javascript. I just need three to show at once.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your css is targeting a class called "select."  Just add the class to the divs and they will show up.  Your id's also need to be unique.  Here's a fix that should work:

```
<div class="select" id="linkdiv1" href="phone-condition" onclick="location.href = $(this).attr('href')+'?/1234/#iPhone';return false"></div>
<div class="select" id="linkdiv2" href="phone-condition" onclick="location.href = $(this).attr('href')+'?/1234/#iPhone';return false"></div>
<div class="select" id="linkdiv3" href="phone-condition" onclick="location.href = $(this).attr('href')+'?/1234/#iPhone';return false"></div>
```

see it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/mHU84/

Comment: The `div's` already have a class. Check the javascript. And I've already tried assigning individual `id's` but still only one but shows up.